# wp-admin is opening but the site isn't opening

Tags: wp-admin, xampp

I had changed my port from 80 to 8080 in xampp server. After heading to localhost:8080/mysite/wp-admin/ I am able to see my wordpress dashboard. From there, when I click on visit site, it gives my 'This site can't be reached' error. Even my phpmyadmin is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the default port, you should write the port in the `wp_options` table in your database at `siteurl` and `home` after the localhost.

> For example, `localhost/site/wp-admin/` becomes
> `localhost:8080/site/wp-admin/`.

Does this option work for you?